# Is there any docs how Mybatis auto-map the resultSet into Object?

Tags: mybatis

I tried to find documentation on how Mybatis works but was unable to locate it. However, I did find some related issues on https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/2331. Based on my current understanding, Mybatis maps the ResultSet in the following manner:

1. It looks for a no-arguments constructor (also known as a default constructor) and accesses fields using reflection. In this case, setters are not required.
2. If the object does not have a default constructor but has a constructor with more than one parameter, Mybatis maps the data using that constructor. This is called constructor auto-mapping. However, this feature has a problem as it maps the data in the order of declaration.

However, this understanding is not sufficient to fully resolve the issues that I encountered. For instance, when I annotated my DTO with @Data, which was then mapped by Mybatis mapper, the mapper injected data that was previously used into the property that should be null, when the selected column had null value.

### Below contents is added in Mar, 20, 2023

I brought the example code not exactly same with company's but I'm sure that will not be a problem to explain the issue I encountered.

```java
@Data
class MyUserDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String address;

}
```

```java
@Mapper
interface UserMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = #{id}")
    public MyUserDTO findByUserId(@Param("id") Long id)

}
```

and the query result was like below

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = 1;
```

```
id | name | age | address
-------------------------
1  | jin  | 20  | null
```

for this circumstances, when I called the `findByUserId` method and Mapper returned the `MyUserDTO` instance with the result data like this.

```java
...

Long id = req.getId();
MyUserDTO userDTO = userMapper.findByUserId(id)

// userDTO.getId() => 1
// userDTO.getName() => "jin"
// userDTO.getAge() => 20
// userDTO.getAddress() => "20" this value should be null, but mapped age's value

...
```

> #### Environment
>
> spring-boot-2.7.8
> mybatis : 3.5.11
> --- configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case : true
> rdbms : sqlite3
> jdk : AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.11
> os : macOS Ventura v13.2.1

Comment: Try enabling [`argNameBasedConstructorAutoMapping`](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#settings) (note that you also need to add `-parameters` compiler option). The result will be more intuitive in most usages, I believe. If the problem persists, please add 1) the DTO definition, 2) example result set (columns vs. values), 3) the expected DTO values and the actual DTO values (assertEquals() statements are the best).

Comment: @ave thanks for the comments, I've already solved the issue by adding no-args constructor. but I just wonder why does it happened.

Comment: I may be able to explain if you add the information I requested.

Comment: @ave I add some more information, I think the whole code has too much informations, so I made some example code. thanks for the continued interest :D

Comment: Thanks! But I couldn't reproduce the problem. To reproduce the issue, there needs to be an extra column(s) in the result set, I think. Please try this portable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-75762972) and find the key difference to reproduce the issue by comparing it with your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information you provided, I couldn't reproduce the problem, so I will explain one possible scenario that causes the issue you described.
If it does not fit your situation, please update the details so that I can reproduce the problem.

---

Lombok's `@Data` generates the default (a.k.a. no-arg) constructor unless some of the fields are `final`, so I assume that all fields are `final`.

```java
`@Data`
class MyUserDTO {
  private final Long id;
  private final String name;
  private final Integer age;
  private final String address;
}
```

The generated constructor may look like this.

```java
MyUserDTO(Long id, String name, Integer age, String address) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.address = address;
}
```

When MyBatis performs constructor auto-mapping, there are two modes i.e. "order-based" mapping and "arg-name-based" mapping.
The former is the default and the latter was added in version 3.5.10.

With the default "order-based" mapping, MyBatis maps the first column in the result set to the first argument of the constructor, the second column to the second argument, and so on.
And for some reason, in this mode, MyBatis tries to map the column values to fields after invoking the constructor.  This sometimes causes an unexpected mapping result.

For example, if the `address` and `age` are swapped in the result set...

| id | name | address | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jin | null | 20 |

... the constructor is invoked as follows.

```java
new MyUserDTO(1, "jin", null, "20")
```

Note that, at this point, the result is already wrong i.e. `address` is `"20"` and `age` is `null`.

MyBatis then tries to map the columns to the fields using the column names.

- map `1` to `id`
- map `jin` to `name`
- `null` is ignored [1]
- map `20` to `age`

As a result, the column value `20` is set to both `address` and `age`.

Although it may not be the expected behavior, we cannot correct it because it could break existing solutions [2].

---

With the new "arg-name based" mapping, MyBstis maps the value of the column `id` to the first argument of the constructor regardless of the position of the column in the result set (because the name of the first argument of the constructor is `id`).
And most importantly, in this mode, MyBatis does not perform the problematic second mapping.

To switch the mode, you need to 1) set `true` to `argNameBasedConstructorAutoMapping` in the config and 2) add `-parameters` compiler option [3].

---

Lastly, when there are multiple non-default constructors, you should add `@AutoMapConstructor` to the target constructor for auto-mapping.
Without the annotation, MyBatis tries to make a best guess.

---

[1] Unless `callSettersOnNulls` is enabled in the config
[2] Assuming that the value of `address` column is not `null`, the result is correct only because of this behavior.
[3] With Maven, add `<parameters>true</parameters>` in the compiler plugin configuration. IDEs might require extra configuration.